# Pymongo Как найти документ в базе, если значение мне неизвестно(только по ключу)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymongo

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(URL)

Users = client['Tlgam']['Users']

Users.find_one_and_update({'user': [я не знаю какой тут список]}, {{'$set': {'user': [1, 2, 3]}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Получается я не правильно хранил значения
Было так:

```
{'user': [0,6,5]}
```

А надо так:

```
{'user': 'me', 'list': [1,2,3]}

Users.find_one_and_update({'user': 'me'}, {{'$set': {'list': [1, 2, 3]}}})
```